# How to give permissions for folders in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions, file-permissions

I need to give the folder "Temporary ASP.NET Files" a write permission using c#... and I use this code to give it the access

```
DirectoryInfo d1 = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "Temporary ASP.NET Files"));
DirectorySecurity md1 = d1.GetAccessControl();


string user_1 = fa.TextGuestDomain + "\\" + fa.TextGuestUser;
md1.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user_1, FileSystemRights.FullControl,InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));

d1.SetAccessControl(md1);
```

When I checked for the security properties for the folder "Temporary ASP.NET Files" after implementing the code, it didn't checked the "write" permission check-box, instead of that it checked the "special permissions" one... I have noticed that even when I changed the access from write to full control or read , it checked the "special permissions" one....

This is not the problem :), the problem is its not giving the right access that i give to it... when I give it write, it doesn't act like if I give it the write permission. I don't know why !! Am I doing it the wrong way ??

Note:
when I'm doing it in the manual way its working, while when using the coding way. it's not working...

I hope you can help me with that...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know your pain - filesystem ACLs are a pain to modify and even if it seems to work, it might break in some circumstances. In your case, there's a simple solution, fortunately.

The problem lies with `PropagationFlags.InheritOnly`. This means that this permission is *only* applied to items that inherit permissions - e.g. you are granting rights *only for the files in this directory and not in any subdirectories*.

To grant directory rights that inherit "normally" (i.e. propagate to subdirectories and all files), use the following values for InheritanceFlags and PropagationFlags:
`InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit` and `PropagationFlags.None`.

Answer (score 11):

```
private static void GrantAccess(string file)
{
    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(file);
    if (!exists)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(file);
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder is created Sucessfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder already exists");
    }
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
   
}
```

The above code will set the access rights of the folder to full control/ read-write to every user (everyone).

Comment: Works exactly as said. Everyone gets full control

Comment: Did not work for me. I wanted to add some libs into `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.20f1\Editor` and used same script with modification of not creating the directory. I get 
`Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.RaiseExceptionOnFailure (System.Int32 errorCode, System.String name, System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle handle, System.Object context) [0x00024]`

Comment: @blongho Maybe your current process don't have access rights to that location.. Try running it with admin rights